# How to use $resource.get() or $http.get() params

Tags: angularjs

I followed an angular tutorial that uses api.openweathermap.org for the weather app lesson. Because openweathermap.org doesn't have anymore weather data more than 1 day, I found another website that allows you to have weather data for free more than 1 day.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to implement the new demo link in the tutorial link, inside $resource.get().

Code for api.openweathermap.org:

With $resource

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?");
$scope.key = 'sdfdfdsfdsfsdfrtrt';
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({q: $scope.city, appid: $scope.key});
```

With $http:

```
var query = city + ', ' + country;
$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?', {
params: {
    q: query,
    appid: key
}
```

Output:

```
openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boston,usa&appid=xddfdfreredfwsere
```

New link from api.wunderground.com

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/xfgfgffgghghrer/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json
```

My issue is that in openweathermap after ? you can use your params easy, but on wunderground you have a lot of  / / to separate the params.

So far I got to this, but doesn't work:

```
$resource("http://api.wunderground.com/api/appid/forecast/q")
```

Can someone please give me a hand with this with $resource or $http?

Comment: Just use string concatenation.

Comment: I don't know what u mean. Please can you show me by example?

Comment: `$http.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + key + '/forecast/q/' + state + '/' + city + '.json')`.

Comment: Thank you. Put it like comment.